# Difference between functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I’m just learning JavaScript and I’m studying other people’s code in order to learn. One thing I’m trying to wrap my head around is the different ways of doing the same thing in JavaScript.

My question is this:

Is `function create(){};` the same as `create: function(){};`?

If not what’s the difference? When to use the one way of typing and when the other? What does the colon mean?

Comment: Read https://kangax.github.io/nfe/ and learn about object literals.

Comment: `create: function` is not a way to create a function by itself. That colon only shows up like that in JS after an object key, so `create: function` would have to be used like `{create: function(){} }`

Comment: That {} isn't a block but an object and seeing create: on it's own line is a valid misunderstanding for beginners.  Don't downvote just because you don't like the question, try to understand it, the purpose of stack overflow is to learn, hard to learn if people are hostile to questions that are valid.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most standard way to create a function:

```
function create(){
    console.log("inside function");
}
```

If a function is a property of an object then you use the colons:

```
myobject = {
    create: function(){
        console.log("inside function");
    }
};
```

Functions can also be assigned:

```
var create = function(){
    console.log("inside function");
}
```

Functions are also objects, there is no difference of them in javascript because javascript is weird like that.  So with above:

```
create.myproperty = true;
```

is valid syntax.

And to make it even weirder, anonymous functions can be assigned like above but can also be self invoked:

```
(function () {
    console.log("inside function");
})();
```

Which is messy but unfortunately used a lot in libraries.

Comment: There's a lot of opinion about "messyness", "weirdness" and "unfortunateness", which I think you are in the minority on. Also "assigned functions" are called "Function Expressions" and there are big differences between using them and "Function Declarations". Your last example is an "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" and is a very popular (and many believe, elegant) pattern to encapsulate code and protect the module from polluting higher scopes.

Comment: Assigning a function to a variable is referred to also as a function assignment, function expression is valid too though it is less descriptive of what it actually is since it doesn't express anything.  Also even w3 schools refers to self invoked functions as such.  Also there's a lot of malarkey in OOP, majority doesn't make it right.  Function declartions is much more general, there's many ways to declare a function, even anonymously.

Comment: Hey, I'm just trying to help you out. Your terminology is not accurate (an assignment is just a type of expression) and W3 Schools is well-known **not** to be a good resource for accurate, up-to-date and reliable information.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: I don't think you really are, I think you're trying to be right.  Which ok, I'll at least tell you what I know and think.  It's easy to criticize any resource but you're acting like any terminology not your own is wrong, which is also wrong.  There's many different areas of programming and terminology most used can even be more popular in one language than another, it might benefit you to understanding other people better if you kept a more open mind and less rigid and narrow sense of right and wrong when the purpose of words is to communicate.

Comment: Again, I'm just trying to help you out. Your desire for there to be shades of grey doesn't make it so. These are very specific terms because they have very specific meanings with very specific connotations. It's also not "my" opinions I'm trying to express here, it's the actual terminology created and used by the creator of JavaScript (Brenden Eich), ECMA (the standard-bearers of the language) and the JavaScript community at large. Wanting to call something a term that you like better is great for you, but it doesn't make it the right term to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I understand what’s going on better now. The example of the function being a property of the object is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is a great post. It has humanity and reality to it which is sadly missing from A LOT of answers here on SO.

Comment: "Because javascript is weird like that". "...and to make it weirder". Words spoken by a human, hence 'humanity'. Writing javascript can feel weird (compared to OOP languages) at times, hence the 'reality'.

Comment: I'd like to also add, that the first example of creating a function I showed is standard across more languages than just javascript and a lot of the other ways of using or creating functions in javascript are very rare in other langauges if they exist at all.

Answer (score 3):

The colon syntax alone doesn't mean you are making a function. It's used when creating an Object Literal. The colon acts as an assignment operator (like `=`) to give the object's properties their values.

In JavaScript, objects really just have properties (not methods). But, those properties can store functions (functions are data in JavaScript).

So, here's an object literal that creates some properties:

```js
var myObject = {
  property1: "42",
  anotherProperty: true,
  aPropertyThatStoresAFunction: function(){
    console.log("You invoked the function stored in the property!");
  }
};

// Now, we can access the object's properties:
console.log(myObject.property1);
console.log(myObject.anotherProperty);
console.log(myObject.aPropertyThatStoresAFunction); // Notice here the actual function's code is logged?

// But, since functions are also bits of invocable code, if you access the function
// stored in the property and then add () on to the end of it, you can invoke the function
myObject.aPropertyThatStoresAFunction();
```